# Заполнение массива элементами другого массива

Tags: c#, динамические-массивы

У меня есть такой код:

```
Dictionary<int, Element> Month = new Dictionary<int, Element>();
List<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();


public class Element
{
    public int[] No;
    public int[] Yes;
    public Element(int[] no, int[] yes)
    {
        No = no;
        Yes = yes;
    }
}
```

В `Dictionaty` ключ это число месяца. Каждому числу в месяце хочу присвоить `Element`. Все возможные варианты присвоения хранятся в `Elements`. Свойства `No` и `Yes` это числа месяца когда обязательно нужно присвоить и когда присваивать нельзя. Задача в том что бы заполнить `Month` элементами максимально рпвномерно, чтобы между одинаковыми элементами было минимум два других. Количество элементов в `Elements` около десяти. Количество элементов в `Yes` и `No` от нуля до трёх.

Всё что получилось у меня жуткая каша из наслоения циклов и проверок, но увы нерабочая от слова совсем. Помогите решить проблему или подскажите верные инструменты для ее решения.

Пример входных данных:

```
Elements.Add(new Element(new[] { 1, 2 }, null));
Elements.Add(new Element(new[] { 17 }, new[] { 10 }));
Elements.Add(new Element(null, null));
Elements.Add(new Element(null, new[] { 11 }));
```

Comment: Для начала чётко сформулируйте вопрос. Вы хотите присвоить Element: сначала каждому месяцу, потом пишете "максимально равномерно", при этом не объясняя правило, какие элементы считаются одинаковыми. Входные данные для заполнения вы храните в списке elements и его же хотите присвоить в дни. Вопрос непонятен. Алгоритм непонятен. Опишите задачу более подробно.

Comment: Итого у вас есть входные данные: `int[] no` -- набор дней, которые заполнять нельзя и `int[] yes` -- набор дней, которые должны быть строго заполнены. Давайте такие данные будут, а не `public Element(int[] no, int[] yes)`, хорошо? Вам нужно сформировать результат в виде new `Dictionary<int, Element>()` -- что же туда нужно присвоить а? годится присваивать `new Element()`?

Comment: @A K♦ а количество дней узнаю вот так DateTime.DaysInMonth(DateTime.Today.Year, DateTime.Today.Month);

Comment: @A K♦ в Dictionary ключ день месяца от 1 до 31 значение экземпляр класса `Element` эти экземпляры я беру из колекции `Elements`

Comment: Меня просто убивает вот какой момент: есть какие дни месяца, которые ничем не надо заполнять -- ну допустим. Есть дни, которые строго нужно заполнить. Если день может быть строго ЛИБО заполнен, ЛИБО не заполнен -- то откуда взялось условие по равномерности заполнения? Что с чем сравнивается? Какие расстояния, какие количества элементов между двумя?? Если же в месяце тридцать дней, а в елемент с десяток дней -- будут какие-то пропуски. Что заполняем, как? Какой смысл в заполнении дней месяца теми же самыми данными, что и входной набор данных?

Comment: @A K♦ день заполнен или незаполнен для каждого отдельного `Element`, тоисть если день нельзя заполнить одним элементом то его нужно заполнить другим

Comment: Может быть, если у вас какая-то практическая задача типа "заполнение расписания смен", то вы её приведёте в исходном виде? Сейчас даже постановка задачи весьма сумбурна -- понятно, что решить её затруднительно даже вам самому.